# React Native Typescript: Al registrar un nuevo usuario y seleccionar el rol “admin”, éste se guarda con el rol “repartidor”

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, typescript, native

espero me ayuden con este código en react native: ¿Que está mal de este código en react native typescript? Al registrar un nuevo usuario y seleccionar el rol “admin”, éste se guarda con el rol “repartidor”). Uso dropdown-picker para seleccionar los roles (“Admin” y “Repartidor”.
Este es el código que se usa en el archivo DeliveryCreate.tsx, donde se ingresan los datos del usuario y la seleccion de los roles con DropDownPicker :

```
export const AdminDeliveryCreateScreen = () => {
const { name, lastname, phone, email, password, confirmPassword, open, value, items, 
responseMessage, loading, image, onChange, takePhoto, pickImage, setOpen, setValue, 
setItems, getRoles, createDelivery } = useViewModel();
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
  if (responseMessage !== '') {
    ToastAndroid.show(responseMessage, ToastAndroid.LONG);
    } getRoles();
  }, [responseMessage])

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.imageContainer}
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
        >
            {
                image == ''
                    ? <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../../../../../../assets/image_new.png')}
                    />
                    : <Image
                        source={{ uri: image }}
                        style={styles.image}
                    />
            }
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={styles.form}>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
                <CustomTextInput
                    placeholder='Nombres'
                    image={require('../../../../../../assets/user.png')}
                    keyboardType='default'
                    property='name'
                    value={name}
                    onChangeText={onChange}
                />
                <CustomTextInput
                    placeholder='Apellidos'
                    keyboardType='default'
                    image={require('../../../../../../assets/my_user.png')}
                    property='lastname'
                    onChangeText={onChange}
                    value={lastname}
                />
                <CustomTextInput
                    placeholder='Correo electronico'
                    keyboardType='email-address'
                    image={require('../../../../../../assets/email.png')}
                    property='email'
                    onChangeText={onChange}
                    value={email}
                />
                <CustomTextInput
                    placeholder='Telefono'
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    image={require('../../../../../../assets/phone.png')}
                    property='phone'
                    onChangeText={onChange}
                    value={phone}
                />
                <CustomTextInput
                    placeholder='Contraseña'
                    keyboardType='default'
                    image={require('../../../../../../assets/password.png')}
                    property='password'
                    onChangeText={onChange}
                    value={password}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <CustomTextInput
                    placeholder='Confirmar Contraseña'
                    keyboardType='default'
                    image={require('../../../../../../assets/confirm_password.png')}
                    property='confirmPassword'
                    onChangeText={onChange}
                    value={confirmPassword}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            <View style={{ bottom: 30 }}>
                <View>
                    <DropDownPicker
                        placeholder='SELECCIONE UN ROL'
                        open={open}
                        value={value}
                        items={items}
                        setOpen={setOpen}
                        setValue={setValue}
                        setItems={setItems}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ marginTop: 10, bottom: 20 }}>
                <RoundedButton
                    text='REGISTRAR NUEVO REPARTIDOR'
                    onPress={() => createDelivery()}
                />
            </View>
        </View>

        <ModalPickImage
            openGallery={pickImage}
            openCamera={takePhoto}
            modalUseState={modalVisible}
            setModalUseState={setModalVisible}
        />
        {
            loading &&
            <ActivityIndicator
                style={MyStyles.loading}
                size="large"
                color={MyColors.primary}
            />
        }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Este es el código de ViewModel.tsx, donde esta la funcion de createDelivery, ahi es donde me genera el error, en el if y el else. Alguien me puede ayudar por favor. Tal vez la solución es mas fácil de lo que creo.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { DeliveryContext } from '../../../../context/DeliveryContext';
import { Rol } from '../../../../../Domain/entities/Rol';
import { GetRolesUserUseCase } from '../../../../../Domain/useCases/rol/GetRolesUser';

interface DropDownProps {
    label: string,
    value: string
}

const AdminDeliveryCreateViewModel = () => {

const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    image: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
});
const [roles, setRoles] = useState<Rol[]>([]);
const [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState('');
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [file, setFile] = useState<ImagePicker.ImagePickerAsset>()
const { registerAdminWithImage, registerWithImage } = useContext(DeliveryContext);
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
const [items, setItems] = useState<DropDownProps[]>([]);
const [selectedRole, setSelectedRole] = useState(roles[0]);

useEffect(() => {
    setDropDownItems();
}, [roles])

const onChange = (property: string, value: any) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [property]: value });
    setSelectedRole(value);
}

const createDelivery = async () => {
    if (isValidForm() && selectedRole.id === '2') {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await registerWithImage(values, file!);
        setLoading(false);
        setResponseMessage(response.message);
    }
    else {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await registerAdminWithImage(values, file!);
        setLoading(false);
        setResponseMessage(response.message);
    }
}

const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        quality: 1
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
        onChange('image', result.assets[0].uri);
        setFile(result.assets[0]);
    }
}

const takePhoto = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        quality: 1
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
        onChange('image', result.assets[0].uri);
        setFile(result.assets[0]);
    }
}

const setDropDownItems = () => {
    let itemsRoles: DropDownProps[] = [];
    roles.forEach(role => {
        itemsRoles.push({
            label: role.name,
            value: role.id!
        })
    });
    setItems(itemsRoles);
}

const getRoles = async () => {
    const result = await GetRolesUserUseCase();
    console.log('ROLES: ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 3));
    setRoles(result);
}

const isValidForm = (): boolean => {
    if (values.name === '') {
        setErrorMessage('Ingresa tu nombre');
        return false;
    }
    if (values.lastname === '') {
        setErrorMessage('Ingresa tu apellido');
        return false;
    }
    if (values.email === '') {
        setErrorMessage('Ingresa tu correo electronico');
        return false;
    }
    if (values.phone === '') {
        setErrorMessage('Ingresa tu telefono');
        return false;
    }
    if (values.password === '') {
        setErrorMessage('Ingresa la contraseña');
        return false;
    }
    if (values.confirmPassword === '') {
        setErrorMessage('Ingresa la confirmación de la contraseña');
        return false;
    }
    if (values.password !== values.confirmPassword) {
        setErrorMessage('Las contraseñas no coinciden');
        return false;
    }
    if (values.image === '') {
        setErrorMessage('Selecciona una imagen');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

return {
    ...values,
    onChange,
    takePhoto,
    pickImage,
    createDelivery,
    loading,
    roles,
    open,
    value,
    items,
    responseMessage,
    getRoles,
    setOpen,
    setValue,
    setItems
   }
}
export default AdminDeliveryCreateViewModel;
```